# How can I use Array as Object key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, object

I want to make a dictionary that able to get same result with different keys,
so I did something like this in javascript:

```
var dictionary = {
        [CHW,CW] : {                      //CHW and CW is ref to same thing
            [FLOW,FLW,FW] : 'Result 1'    //FLOW, FLW and FW is ref to same thing(Flow)
           }
        }
```

The code above only showing the concept, what I should do to get my expected output below?
 
expected output:

```
dictionary.CHW.FLW   //output: 'Result 1'
dictionary.CW.FLW    //output: 'Result 1'
dictionary.CW.FLOW   //output: 'Result 1'
dictionary.ABC.EFG   //output:  undefined
```

My ultimate goal is to able to get the same output by calling different keys in the dictionary. Is there any library/Logic that can do so?
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: Just use string keys whose values are themselves objects

Comment: If you want the same key to return the same result as another key, that is simply pointing the secondary key to the first keys value.  `var x = { a: 3 }; x.b = x.a;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain object can't do that, a Map can:

> The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value (both objects and primitive values) may be used as either a key or a value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Are you saying that if the user made a `Map` with a key of `["x", "y"]"`, that they could access in the map `mapVar.x` and `mapVar.y`, even though the key, in actuality, is an array and not those unique values?

Comment: thanks for helping, it really solved my problem, I can use `map.get("example_key")` to get what i want now

Answer (score 0):

you can create computed property in the object. Here I am assuming you are storing key in variable.

```
var dictionary = {
        [CHW] : {
              [CW]: {
                      [FLOW] : 'Result 1'
                    }
                  }
              }
```

now you can access the way you want.
dictionary[CHW][CW][FLLOW] give you 'Result 1'

Comment: Updated the solution, I was assuming that keys are stored in variable.